# Where can I find good open source code flow visualization software?

Tags: visualization

I am working on an academic research regarding some very long functions in the Linux kernel ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127588/why-are-some-functions-extremely-long-ideas-needed-for-an-academic-research), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134174/can-this-kernel-function-be-more-readable-ideas-needed-for-an-academic-research)).

For that research, I would like to use some code flow visualization tool, that would be able to plot a graph in which each vertex is a decision point and each edge is a piece of code which runs in a consequent way.

Do you know of any good, open source project that can visualize C code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps a tool like [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) would be of help.  It generates call graphs based on actual calls and cannot pre-generate a call graph without actually running the program, which may not suit your needs, but then it again it may.

[image: KCacheGrind Call Graph]

Answer (score 1):

[History flow's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/historyflow/) are very neat for changes/diff across multiple versions.

Codeplex has a project, [Dependency Visualizer](http://dependencyvisualizer.codeplex.com/) which does support C also.

[Gprof2Dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) can render oprofile, this would get you dynamic info also.

[CodeViz](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/codeviz/) also (static tool) would work.

If your using gcc, gcc-xml has an [introspector plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspector_(program)) also todo this.

Answer (score 1):

You appears to want to acquire a flowchart of C source code ("decisions", "code blocks").
Something like this [C flowchart](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/C-dataflow-example.jpg)?

To do this correctly, esp. for Linux kernal code, I'd expect you to have to preprocess the code first to get rid of macros and conditionals.   I would assume that GCC would construct such a graph internally and that you ought to be able to get your hands on that graph.

Answer (score 0):

[**Doxygen**](http://www.doxygen.nl/) does some amount of 'visualization',
but you need to work on the code a bit for it to be usable.

---

Another interesting thing to check would be [**lxr**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/)

> [**Linux Cross Referencer**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/) is a software toolset for indexing and presenting source code repositories. LXR was initially targeted at the Linux source code, but has proved usable for a wide range of software projects. [**lxr.linux.no**](http://lxr.linux.no/) is currently running an experimental fork of the LXR software.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Sourcetrail](https://github.com/CoatiSoftware/Sourcetrail). Can work with a compile_commands.json. Not sure if it's still maintained, though. But it's foss and you can fork it!