# Visualize my app's Java source code complexity -- tool for windows?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I am looking for a tool like that excellent one proposed in the accepted answer to question [Where can I find good open source code flow visualization software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136728/where-can-i-find-good-open-source-code-flow-visualization-software). But -- *I am bound to Windows*.

I want to visualize the complexity of the functionalities.

I don´t need a navigational aid. All I want is visualize what is going on under the hood in terms of complexity.

(This is not because my status as a dev is at zero. It is because I am addressing a non-technical audience in a presentation, and the app's complexity is largely unknown to them, and they often underestimate it.

And yes, I understand there are lots of other obvious options to communicate the message to such an audience.

But anyways -- I am looking for a possibly sexy-graph-producing, yet easy-to-use, tool, be it static (source-code analyzing) or dynamic (analyzing only active execution paths at runtime). That would be just cool, yet still quite honest and authentic.)

A class hierarchy diagram would not be sufficient because it doesn't reflect the functional complexity involved.

Feel free to migrate this elsewhere if such a question is offtopic at SO, and sorry for that in advance, then.

And thanks for all thoughts, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into Sonar.  It is almost industry standard for Java development these days: http://www.sonarsource.org/

Comment: Particularly given a non-technical audience, Sonar is definitely the way to go. Call graphs aren't a meaningful way of condensing complexity, package tangle, technical debt etc.

Comment: Mmh, when I use the online dashboard stuff, I get an [Object error] messagebox, and only partial results. Also, it is targeted to an audience that gets along with source code metrics etc. My audience is in the business CEO class, not the software dev class. Unfortunately ;|

Comment: Currently I can not download Sonar, at 99%, I get a server disconnect. Will check that one later, thanks so far.